# Adding Arabic sources to my bibliography

Tags: citations, thesis

Should I dedicate a separate part in my bibliography for my Arabic sources and thus write them in Arabic letters, or should I transliterate them and include them within the whole bibliography like any other source. I've searched the latest version of MLA (8th. ed.) and found nothing relevant. Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: How many do you cite? How important are they? Are your readers likely to understand Arabic?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/translating-transliterating-foreign-bibliography-references), and the answers to it? It's about Russian sources, and the type of text in question is not a thesis, but a paper to be published in a journal, but you might find the answers helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Superbest, quite a large number. And yes, but the thesis is originally in English and is meant to address scholars and English speakers in Arabic-speaking communities as well as English-speaking ones.

Comment: Based on how it's normally done for foreign titles in Latin script — no translation as a general rule, bracketed translations of necessary — I would say your best bet is to cite them in Arabic script (we need to be able to give the source easily, working from a transliteration makes that hard) putting their Latin forms in brackets. But as I imagine you'll be translating for in-text, you might flip that. But I'd look up some theses already done and see how they do it and follow

Comment: Check with the office at your school that sets the thesis formatting guidelines.