# Should items in a bibliography be translated into English or left in their original languages?

Tags: citations

I'm working on a bibliography. Most of the items on the list are Chinese language sources. I have translated the majority of them into English but I'm wondering if this is the correct way of going about it. The readers of the piece are highly unlikely to be able to read Chinese. Should I leave them in the source language or translate them into a language that the readers will be able to understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should references in non-Latin script language be treated in English paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/how-should-references-in-non-latin-script-language-be-treated-in-english-paper)

Comment: @GoodDeeds It definitely tells me how to do it if I want to do it that way.

Comment: You can use both: List the original and provide a translation.